Post an improved version or edit the original
This comes up somewhat often and I am not sure how it should be handled.  A new user (well, any user but it always seems to be a new one) asks a poorly structured question which quickly (and appropriately) gets closed.  They then post an improved version of the question.
Should we then close the new one and propose that the original be improved?  Or just let the new one proceed as if the original never existed?
My instincts are to push to get the original improved, but I think that's at least partially inspired by the fact that people often simply repost the closed original while making no changes at all, or only cosmetic changes.  Perhaps a different response is appropriate in cases where the new version represents a significant upgrade?
Should add:  I searched for a duplicate of this question, unsuccessfully.  If one is supplied, I'll gladly delete this version.  I could post an example of the phenomenon, if that's desired, but it's not my intent to call attention to any particular user.

A dorky opinion: it's OK to create a replacement post iff

the original post

if repaired, invalidates some good Answer

or

hasn't received any good Answer and has been deleted

or

is undeletable and has been downvoted,



and

the new post is a significant upgrade.


Thanks.  Doesn't seem like anybody has a strong view and your position seems reasonable.

I disagree with your first bullet point. Such an Answer is not the correct answer. Even if it answered the Question as stated, this is immaterial, because the Question had a mistake which meant it wasn't the question the asker meant to ask. The only good that such an Answer might contain is giving a clue to the OP that they should correct the Question. Punishing the asker by closing their Question is not a good response, I feel; at least let them correct it.

@RosieF I can't follow at all. What exactly are you disagreeing with?

I disagree with the idea that if the asker asks a good question in good faith, but someone sees a quibble with it which allows an interpretation which the asker didn't intend and posts an Answer to that unintended interpretation, then the asker should create a replacement post. I think the asker should be allowed to correct the Question.

A Question with a legitimate Answer shouldn't be changed in a way that invalidates the Answer. In any case, I don't know why you'd consider creating a new post (as opposed to editing the original post) to be a punishment, or why you are mistakenly thinking that I've suggested anything about question closure.

One possible problem to anticipate if you edit your Question...
I once had a guy completely misunderstand my Question, post a non-useful Answer, get angry at my appreciative but clarifying comments, then get even angrier at my clarifying edits to the Question (that I don't think were even necessary).  Not everyone is that extreme, but it's a example of why posting a new Question is sometimes better and necessary.
